# How do I push arrays to array inside a recursive javascript function so that I can use it when it's done?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

First question here (I think). Please let me know if additional information is needed in order for you guys to help me out.

So I'm trying to implement an algorithm in javascript that uses a recursive funtion.

The function is copied from [Implementing Heap Algorithm of Permutation in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@paulrohan/implemetning-heap-algorithm-to-find-permutation-of-a-set-of-numbers-in-javascript-d6b6ef8ee0e) and looks like this:

```
let swap = function(array, index1, index2) {
    let temp = array[index1]
    array[index1] = array[index2]
    array[index2] = temp
    return array
}

let permutationHeap = (array, result, n) => {
    n = n || array.length // set n default to array.length
    if (n === 1) {
        result(array)
    } else {
        for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            permutationHeap(array, result, n - 1)
            if (n % 2) {
                swap(array, 0, n - 1) // when length is odd so n % 2 is 1,  select the first number, then the second number, then the third number. . . to be swapped with the last number
            } else {
                swap(array, i - 1, n - 1) // when length is even so n % 2 is 0,  always select the first number with the last number
            }
        }
    }
}


let output = function(input) {
    console.log(output)
}

permutationHeap([1,2,3,4,5], output)
```

The console.log in the output function (callback?) gives me the right output. If I move that console.log below the if statement in permutationHeap-function, I get the right output as well (console.log(array), in that case though).

What I want to do is to store every output as an array, inside an array that I can use later on down the road. I'm guessing that I'm struggling with Javascript 101 here. Dealing with asynchronus thinking. But can't for the life of me figure out how to get that array of arrays!

- If I declare an empty array outside the permutationHeap-function and
  .push(array) it only stores [1,2,3,4,5]. Same deal if I do the same
  thing inside the output-function.
- I've also tried passing in an empty array to the
  permutationHeap-function and push that way. Still no luck.

Anyone who's willing to shine some light over a probably super nooby question? :) Much appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually broke the algorithm in my previous answer, because by duplicating the array ever iteration I broke the part of the algorithm that relies on the array changing as it goes.

I've made an answer that uses the code that you had originally more effectively:

```js
var swap = function(array, index1, index2) {
  var temp = array[index1];
  array[index1] = array[index2];
  array[index2] = temp;
  return array;
};

var permutationHeap = function(array, result, n) {
  n = n || array.length; // set n default to array.length
  if (n === 1) {
    result(array);
  } else {
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      permutationHeap(array, result, n - 1);
      if (n % 2) {
        swap(array, 0, n - 1); // when length is odd so n % 2 is 1,  select the first number, then the second number, then the third number. . . to be swapped with the last number
      } else {
        swap(array, i - 1, n - 1); // when length is even so n % 2 is 0,  always select the first number with the last number
      }
    }
  }
};

function getPermutations(array) {
  var results = [];
  var output = function(res) {
    results.push(res.slice(0));
  }

  permutationHeap(array, output);

  return results;
}

var permutations = getPermutations([1,2,3]);
console.log(permutations);
```

Comment: I saw that my originally accepted answer had some flaws. The code seemed to be wokring, but sadly not. It does work now though! Thanks for all your help and input.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to fix your code by using generators and yield. I can't exactly explain it though...

```js
var swap = function(array, index1, index2) {
    let temp = array[index1]
    array[index1] = array[index2]
    array[index2] = temp
    return array
}

var permutationHeap = function*(array, result, n) {
    n = n || array.length // set n default to array.length
    if (n === 1) {
        yield (array.slice(0))
    } else {
        for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            yield* permutationHeap(array, result, n - 1)
            if (n % 2) {
                swap(array, 0, n - 1) // when length is odd so n % 2 is 1,  select the first number, then the second number, then the third number. . . to be swapped with the last number
            } else {
                swap(array, i - 1, n - 1) // when length is even so n % 2 is 0,  always select the first number with the last number
            }
        }
    }
}

var x = permutationHeap([1,2,3,4,5])
var results = Array.from(x);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Running this gives "output is not defined". When adding back that little function, the console.log(results) outpus a bunch of [1,2,3,4,5] arrays :(

Somehting I'm missing? Running in node.js

Comment: I edited the code, try again. It was just an undefined variable i left in, because I didn't use your 'output' function

Comment: Thanks for helping out! 
console.log(results) outputs arrays containing [1,2,3,4,5]. So something is missing I guess.

Comment: Ah, yes, the array needs to be a copy at the top of the function. Add `array = array.slice(0);` at the top of the function, I'll edit

Comment: No problem, you did all the hard work. I just put `yield` on everything

Comment: @Nicklas the code I posted above does not, in fact, work. The part where I make a slice of the array actually breaks the algorithm!

Comment: @Nicklas haha, I actually made one final edit to this answer. The answer was fine, I just needed to move the place where it does the `slice(0)` call. This answer works. The answer below works too.